# How do I reorder page elements placed with Display Suite?

Tags: 7, display-suite

I want to change the stacking order of a certain page of a website of a client of mine. It's quite simple what I really want. You can check the screenshot. The website's current Drupal version is 7.59.

[image: Changing the layout of this page]

I want to move the category text section (the red section) beneath the section with the four category circles (the blue section), so that the section with the four category circles will be placed at the top.

Since I am a Drupal-beginner I could not find a good solution for it. You might think that this problem could be solved by using CSS by using display: flex and change the stacking order. The problem with display: flex that it moves the whole html view-mode-parent class including the title (Safety Showers). I want the title to be left alone and only the category text to be moved, but its not possible it's in the same html class (view-mode-parent).

This kind of page-template is used through out the whole website, as to be seen here: https://www.matcon.com/en

I noticed that the 2 sections are in a block, but that block is not listed at /admin/structure/block. I also couldn't find a view about it that is listed at admin/structure/views

I also checked all the options at "Manage display" but it does not contain the possibilities to do what I want. It only contains options for the specific sections (like the category text section or the category circles section) but not for the whole thing.

I got the impression that I maybe have to use some kind of hook in order to achieve my goal? If so, which hook should I use?

Comment: Hey, welcome to Drupal Answers. It's really difficult to give you a decent answer as you are mixing up a lot of words here and we actually don't know for sure how these elements got placed there. It could be fields than you simply have to reorder them at the manage display settings http://d7.localhost/admin/structure/types/manage/article/display, it could be blocks then you simply have to reorder them at the blocks layout page http://d7.localhost/admin/structure/block, but it could also be lots of other ways these elements got placed there. So, I'd guess you have to figure this out yourself.

Comment: Looking at the CSS classes, the elements mot likely got placed with [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) which really is a mighty "monster" IMHO. You might want to watch some tuts about it maybe on YT to learn how it's working.

Comment: I changed the title and tags in a way that hopefully attracts people who know Display Suite better than the both of us. If you don't like the changes, please change it back. Honestly your question still is quite broad, some may find it too broad and most likely vote to close it because of that. But maybe you have some starting points now too find a way yourself.